# DataGrip truncates the table name after 38 characters

Tags: datagrip

I have the problem that DataGrip truncates all table names after 38 characters. See picture.

[image]

We use Oracle 12.2.0, so table names should be allowed to contain 128 bytes, right? In DbForge the tables are displayed correctly, in DataGrip an entry is displayed in the table list but they cannot be opened.

I am using the driver ver. 12.2.0.1 [latest]. How can I fix the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, Oracle 12 officially is not yet supported in DataGrip. Before 12 there was a 30-character limit for table names.

Expect the fix in DataGrip 2019.3

Comment: Okay, thanks for the quick answer! 
P.S. Keep it up! I love your tools!

Comment: Well, we've made a small fix only for names for 2019.2. Expect 2019.2 RC version today.